# How to delete all previous posts by user, whenever they create a new one

Tags: php, wordpress, posts

I am working on a site where specific users are allowed front end creation of posts. I do this with WP User Frontend. I was wondering if there is a way to delete the previous post of a user, whenever they post a new one? I'm pretty comfortable with PHP, so hardcoding something to make this work is no problem.

Comment: So if I understand your question correctly, this will essentially mean that each user can only have 1 post at a time? Are we talking about moving the previous post to bin, or completely removing it?

Comment: You are understanding correctly yes - bin or removal does not really matter, I just need it gone, as I show the posts on the frontpage, and I only need each user to be able to have one post up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to do this is to break up what you need to do in steps, and build your query from there.

Here are the steps I took:

1. Create a loop of all posts that a user has under his/her name. This can be done by using the normal [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) functionality and using the *Author* arguments alongside the [get_current_user_id()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_current_user_id/) WordPress function.
2. Create a counter which incremements at the end of your function
3. Check the current state of the counter, and if it is not on the very first post, delete the post that it is on.

Here's the code that I put together. I've hooked the function onto `admin_init` which could slow the backend down if you have A LOT of concurrent users, in which case it would probably be safer to just hook it into a post_save type action.

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'removing_older_posts' );
function removing_older_posts() {
    $args = array (
        'post_type'         => 'post',
        'author'            => get_current_user_id(),
        'orderby'           => 'date',
        );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $query->have_posts() ) { //if the current user has posts under his/her name
        $i = 0; //create post counter
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) { //loop through each post
            $query->the_post(); //get the current post
            if ($i > 0) { //if you're not on the first post
                wp_delete_post( $query->post->ID, true ); //delete the post
            }
            $i++; //increment the post counter
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This works. Although for some reason, it deleted all posts from a few authors, not sure why, but testing it subsequently, it works like a charm. And no problem with deleted posts, as the project is still just being tested.

Comment: Happy to help :) I'm not sure why it would be deleting all posts from some of your Authors, if you figure it out, do let me know so that I can add the details to my answer, I'll also have a look around and let you know if I find anything :)

Comment: I have no idea either, I looked over the code, and tested it out multiple times since, and I can't seem to recreate the problem. Thanks a lot for the quick help :)

Answer (score 1):

I think there are some options to do this. But I prefer to use WP REST API if you running the latest wordpress version

First get the posts from certain author ( author id ) with this url

```
http://yourwebsite/wp/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?author=3
```

from there you will get some posts fields that posted by that author . You just need to get posts ids and choose which id you want to delete with the next function ( delete post ). in your case you just need to keep the first (latest) .post id.

Delete Posts 
after you get post ids you want to delete you can running WP REST API delete posts function. In this process you need authentication process. I suggest you to use WP Basic Auth plugin since I feel it's easier than the other authentication process.

reference : 
http://v2.wp-api.org/reference/posts/

Comment: Basically you want me to create code that constantly checks if any author has more than one post, and if they do, delete the older ones? Wouldn't this be very performance heavy? Or am I misunderstanding completely - I haven't used the WP REST API yet, so it could simply be ignorance. I am running the latest wordpress version.

Comment: it's up to where or how your function to be executed. In my opinion. It can be executed only when a certain user success create a new post, so it wont be run continuously, only when an author / user create a new post.